# Apexchart tickPlacement 'on' changing the legend of the chart to numbers

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, apexcharts

[toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu7h9.png)
Im trying to put this tools above my chart, after some research i saw that putting tickPlacement: 'on' inside the x-axis solve the problem, but heres the other problem im facing

After i put tickPlacement: 'on' this happens
[All the legend turn into numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzRNQ.png)

Here is what looks like before i put tickPlacement on

[before tickPlacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUeAF.png)

```
mountChart(data) {
      this.chartOptions = {
        title: {
          text: 'Quantidade de Materiais',
          align: 'center',
          style: {
            fontSize: '16px'
          }
        },
        subtitle: {
          text: `${this.filters.join(' / ')}`,
          align: 'center',
          style: {
            fontSize: '10px'
          }
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: data.categories,
          labels: {
            show: false
          }
        },
        yaxis: [
          {
            axisTicks: {
              show: true
            },
            axisBorder: {
              show: true,
              color: '#00E396'
            },
            labels: {
              style: {
                color: '#00E396'
              },
              formatter: (value) => `${kFormatter(value)}`
            },
            title: {
              text: 'Quantidade',
              style: {
                color: '#00E396'
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        plotOptions: {
          bar: {
            horizontal: false,
            dataLabels: {
              position: 'top'
            },
            columnWidth: '45%',
            distributed: true
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          offsetY: -15,
          textAnchor: 'middle',
          style: {
            fontSize: '10px',
            colors: ['#000']
          },
          formatter(val) {
            return `${formatThousandsNotation(val)}`
          }
        },
        stroke: {
          show: true,
          width: 1,
          colors: ['#fff']
        },
        tooltip: {
          fixed: {
            enabled: true,
            position: 'topLeft',
            offsetY: 30,
            offsetX: 60
          },
          y: {
            formatter(val) {
              return `${formatThousandsNotation(val)}`
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          horizontalAlign: 'center',
          showForSingleSeries: true
        },
        noData: {
          text: 'Sem dados',
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
          style: {
            color: '#008FFB',
            fontSize: '20px'
          }
        },
        chart: {
          defaultLocale: 'ptBR',
          locales: [{
            name: 'ptBR',
            options: {
              toolbar: {
                download: 'Exportar',
                selection: 'Seleção',
                selectionZoom: 'Zoom',
                zoomIn: 'Ampliar',
                zoomOut: 'Reduzir',
                pan: 'Arrastar',
                reset: 'Reset Zoom'
              }
            }
          }],
          zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            type: 'y'
          },
          toolbar: {
            show: true,
            tools: {
              download: true,
              zoomin: true,
              zoomout: true,
              pan: true,
              reset: true
            },
            export: {
              csv: {
                filename: `${this.chartID}.csv`,
                columnDelimiter: ';',
                headerCategory: 'Material'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      this.series = data.series
    },
```

How can i add the toolbar options without making the chart legend turn into numbers ?

Comment: `tickPlacement` should have no influence over the categories. I suspect you forgot the comma or something similar and the `categories: data.categories,` line didn't get parsed. It should have no bearing on the toolbar either, whose position may be controlled by `chart.toolbar.offsetX` and `chart.toolbar.offsetY`, as per the [docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/toolbar/). The solution to your problem requires debugging, so please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that might be a forkable stackblitz or codesandbox